# iphone - Making a MKMap black and white

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview

There's a thread that asks the same thing, [Black and white overlay for an MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989208/black-and-white-overlay-for-an-mkmapview)
but I have my doubts if the answer will work, no-one claimed to get it done.

A filter is a function applied to the pixels of an image, so making a Overlay with a monochrome filter will only be applied to the Overlay, not to the map.

Am I right?If not please tell me so, If Im right do you know any other way to make a MKMap to appear in B&W?

Thanks.