# MKMapView set style to black and white

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

i'm trying to change the color scheme of the MKMapView to black and white. It's discussed in this topic: [Black and white overlay for an MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989208/black-and-white-overlay-for-an-mkmapview) but i have no clue how to achieve this.

Can somebody help me out?

Best regards,
Lukas

Comment: The answer to that question describes a workaround that involves a custom `MKOverlayView` that basically covers the entire map, takes a screen grab of the map underneath it, and transforms the grab into monochrome manually [(via this discussion)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html). Can you be more specific what more clarification you seek?

Comment: Thank's for your comment! I'm just trying to replace the diferent colors of the mapview with different grey step colors. SOmething like this: http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/05/20/make-your-google-map-stand-out-with-styles/

Comment: Perhaps [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354925/maptypestyle-in-mapkit) will be of more help as well.

Comment: Are you able to do it using apple/google map's mapkit framework.

Comment: Hey, it's basically possible.. the solution i came up with was, to use a tiles overlay.. It's what Ryan Artecona mentioned in the first place. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is pretty straightforward. By using the GoogleMaps SDK you can set a mapstyle.

One can create styles through the following two sites:
https://snazzymaps.com
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com

Btw: I noticed the GoogleMaps SDK is faster, more developer friendly, and offers more features anyway, so I'd recommend it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Google SDK is an overkill. It changes the fonts and it also flickers between the colors and B/W. There is a simpler solution, Just add a layer like this:

```
   let darkLayer = CALayer()
        darkLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        darkLayer.compositingFilter = "colorBlendMode"
        darkLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(darkLayer)
```

If you want make it a bit darker, you can add another layer:

```
    let darkLayer2 = CALayer()
    darkLayer2.frame = self.view.bounds
    darkLayer2.compositingFilter = "overlayBlendMode"
    darkLayer2.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, 
    alpha: 0.6).cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(darkLayer2)
```

You also wanna force the view to be in dark mode:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    }
```